# Are there browsers that automate download time?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, browser

Are there any browsers that automate downloading time? For example I want to download a huge file during a certain time that I would be unavailable with my device but I'd like the file being downloaded at that exact time. Are there any android browsers that support this kind of feature?
If there aren't what are the ways that I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

### [ADM - Advanced Download Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dv.adm)

It has a browser and scheduled download capability.. It also can intercept the clipboard for download links etc...

Comment: Is it for gingerbread?

Comment: Are there direct .apk download links other than google play? Could you please point to a link that works? The ones that I did find didn't really work? and thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) app and create a recipe for it.

Comment: I don't really know how to create the recipe? Could you be a little more specific, please?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's unlikely that a browser will support such behaviour; I'm not able to find any, and I think it's especially unlikely that they would support Gingerbread. If you had a newer version of Android, you could use [Termux](https://termux.com/) to wait until it was time to start the download, then download the file using something like this command:

```
cd storage/Download; sleep <time in seconds> && wget <url>
```

but unfortunately Termux only supports Android 5.0 Lollipop and newer.

Comment: what about the ADM mentioned above?

Comment: @BeshalJaenal Unfortunately that doesn't work on Gingerbread - you can try downloading it from [APK Mirror](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/dimonvideo/advanced-download-manager/advanced-download-manager-5-1-1-release/advanced-download-manager-5-1-1-android-apk-download/), but it needs at least 4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich to work.